# Message only gets published to one queue in a RabbitMQ Fanout exchange (java)

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

So, I have 2 queues, outboundEmailQueue and storeEmailQueue:

```
<rabbit:queue name="outboundEmailQueue"/>
<rabbit:queue name="storeEmailQueue"/>
```

binded to a fanout exchange called integrationExchange:

```
<rabbit:fanout-exchange name="integrationExchange" auto-declare="true">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="outboundEmailQueue"/>
        <rabbit:binding queue="storeEmailQueue"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:fanout-exchange>
```

the template:

```
<rabbit:template id="integrationRabbitTemplate"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" exchange="integrationExchange"
    message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" return-callback="returnCallback"
    confirm-callback="confirmCallback" />
```

how I am sending an object to the exchange:

```
integrationRabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("integrationExchange", "", outboundEmail);
```

However, the message only gets published to storeEmailQueue:

[image]

[image]

What is wrong with my configuration? Why is the message not being queued to outboundEmailQueue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screen captures, it seems your configuration is ok and the message is reaching both queues.
But the consumer configuration on each queue is not the same:

- storeEmailQueue has consumer ack configured
- outboundEmailQueue has autoack configured

If you have a doubt:

- check the bindings section of either the exchange or the queues to confirm the link is there (but again, from your screen captures, seems likely to be present)
- stop the consumers and push a message to the exchange, you should see the message ready count (and total count) increase on both queues.

Comment: thank you for this! Yes, you are right. The queues have different consumer configuration. With that in mind, I found out that it's the consumer of outboundEmailQueue that has the problem and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I created the same example and its working fine, message is being added to both the queue, But I configure through annotations instead of the XML.  If you want the annotations solution, please follow below link:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803231/how-to-publish-messages-on-rabbitmq-with-fanout-exchange-using-spring-boot`